# How to indicate which CTS module will be effect for our modification on AOSP?

Tags: cts

I'm interesting about the relationship between AOSP sourcecode and CTS test case.

If made some modification on AOSP framework code, How can we know which CTS module will effect.

Comment: It seems that Android Q release a new mechanism
https://source.android.com/compatibility/tests/development/test-mapping

But seems need add test info by self?

Comment: It is quite complicated and not straight fwd.
Basically it is depends on what change you have done in frameworks. There are enough CTS tests present to figure out the compliance quality of framework related changes.